# Is 401k considered a retirement plan offered by an employer?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, retirement

I am trying to brush up on traditional IRA offerings out there.  Specifically, I want to know whether the IRA contribution is tax deductible.

The rules state that I can deduct the full contribution amount unless I am covered by an employer retirement plan.

I am enrolled in my employer's 401k program.  Is that considered an employer provided retirement plan?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

See for instance [this IRS page](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Are-You-Covered-by-an-Employer%27s-Retirement-Plan%3F), which says in part:

> You’re covered by an employer retirement plan for a tax year if your employer (or your spouse’s employer) has a:
>
> Defined contribution plan (profit-sharing, 401(k), stock bonus and money purchase pension plan) and any contributions or forfeitures were allocated to your account for the plan year ending with or within the tax year;